# How to search a wordpress plugin's support forum?

Tags: forum, support

Wordpress.org plugin's have a support forum, but I don't see a way to search it, which makes finding issues related to a specific plugin pretty hard. Am I missing something? or is this option simply not available?

Example of a support forum page:

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-super-cache

Comment: Google is probably your best bet. Use `site:https://wordpress.org/support/topic` and then plugin name and your search term(s).

Comment: Just the site-wide search in the header.  The .org site search works pretty well.  And there is always Google, which you can limit to wordpress.org results with "my search terms site:wordpress.org"

Comment: Ok.. so it is as I thought. It's rather odd that the forum doesn't have it's own search. I was using google and the wordpress search before, but sometimes it takes forever to get to the right place. Thanks.

Comment: The WordPress.org Meta team is working on getting search in plugin sub forums. Although it could take a while seeing as first the bbPress forum audit needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to search within a specific plugin's support threads only and due to the complexity of WordPress's existing network, this is not likely to be addressed any time soon.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-search-these-forums/

However, one can search among a particular plugin's forum {topics} using a similar method to what @Milo posted above in the OP comments. We just need to modify the url a bit.

site:wordpress.org/support/plugin-name/ {query}

This will result in finding a {query} among the paginated support thread titles.

*Also note that since these results are all very similar url's with just the page number being different, one needs to pay attention to Google omitting results and of course one must skim through each of these pages to find the topic matched.

Answer (score 0):

**Not currently possible**.

Although not perfect, @aurovrata has [suggested a method](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-searching-plugin-specific-support-thread/) of searching via google `link:` and `site:` operators:

```
slider form link:wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7-multi-step-module site:wordpress.org/support/topic/
```

An improvement to core SEO has also been [suggested](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/1656) by @aurovrata

There are plans for [improving support search](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7), but such a change seems dependent on [upgrading](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7#comment:22) the main forums version of bbPress, which wouldn't happen until at least version 2.6 is released.

Comment: Update: Wordpress redesign has added a search field to Plugin support forums.
The query uses `buddypress intext:"Plugin: WP Super Cache"`, but it seems **Topic** would be more appropriate `buddypress intext:"Topic: WP Super Cache"`
https://wordpress.org/search/buddypress+intext%3A%22Topic%3A+WP+Super+Cache%22/?forums=1